# how jvm memory allocated when there are more than 1 tomcat running

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

In the catalina.sh file we specify the maximum Xmx size given to the JVM, i am bit confused on the JVM part, do we have seperate JVM for a different tomcat running?? or how would it share one JVM ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one Java program running (such as two Tomcat instances), then they each get their own JVM, with potentially different configuration (or even version).

But if you deploy two webapps into the same Tomcat server, they share a single JVM.

Comment: That being said: current JVMs can usually share *some* memory (mostly the memory needed for loading base libraries & similar things). Don't expect that to amount too much, 'though. The heap is still separate, and that's the biggest part.